# React Native app needs to restart for AsyncStorage to work

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I am currently working on a React Native app that uses AsyncStorage to store authentications tokens for users. I have a context to do this:

```
import React, { useReducer, createContext } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

const initialState = {
  user: null,
};

AsyncStorage.getItem("user").then((res) => {
  if (res !== null || res !== undefined) {
    initialState.user = jwtDecode(res);
  } else return;
});

const AuthContext = createContext({
  user: null,
  login: (userData) => {},
  logout: () => {},
});

function authReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        ...state,
        user: null,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function AuthProvider(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState);

  function login(userData) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("user", userData.token);
    dispatch({
      type: "LOGIN",
      payload: userData,
    });
  }

  function logout() {
    AsyncStorage.clear();
    dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ user: state.user, login, logout }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };
```

My login function looks like this:

```
const [login, { error: loginError }] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER, {
    update(_, { data: { login: userData } }) {
      context.login(userData);
      colorContext.setColor(
        String(
          _palette__colors[
            Math.ceil(Math.random() * _palette__colors.length - 1)
          ]
        )
      );
      navigation.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [{ name: "BottomTab" }],
      });
    },
    variables: {
      email,
      password,
    },
  });
```

However, when I try to login the app returns and error saying that my "user" object is undefined. When I restart the app everything works fine, so it seems as if AsyncStorage needs to manually reload in order to load the data or something. Anyone knows how to resolve this error?

Comment: So I actually figured this out myself. What I had to do was to access the loading variable from GraphQL and then do a conditional for my Login Screen. What happened was that I tried to access the AsyncStorage "user" before it was ready, that's why I got an error